# Smaller notes notation in Chopin's Polonaise Op. 53

Tags: piano, notation, terminology

I encountered a notation in the Chopin's Polonaise, Op. 53 that I have not seen before: smaller font notes not explicitly following the time signature.

[image]

While it is pretty obvious how it is played (fast "dimensionless" passage), I wonder:

- if this notation has a specific name?
- if the technical skill to play it on the piano has a specific name?

Comment: It's a tuplet with lots of notes, or a 'run'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's commonly called a [roulade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulade_(music)), or sometimes [fioritura](https://practisingthepiano.com/chopins-fioritura/) from Italian "flourish."  In his later compositions, they're often more elaborate than just a scale.

It makes no sense to call it a tuplet, unless it's Ferneyhough or Berio ironically quoting Chopin.

Comment: I think you are totally right! Also found [Wiki page on _fioritura_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fioritura) which also features an example from Chopin!

Answer (score 3):

As marcelloverylongname commented, this is a  run.   The notation is  easier than trying to notate 29 notes into 5 eighth-notes.   ( 6-6-6-6-5 ? ugh)

Given that this is in the middle of the piece, in 3/4 time,   with only an eighth-note in that bar,  you should make the run come more or less close to using up the remainder of the meter in that bar.  A little time-stretching is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a term *tirata* (or *tirade*), which I am not sure can be applicable to Chopin.

According to [Artopium Music Index](https://musicterms.artopium.com/t/Tiradetirata.htm), *tirata* is a

> baroque ornament consisting of a long scale passage

Another source, that is actually referenceable, ["Musica Poetica: Musical-Rhetorical Figures in German Baroque Music" by D. Bartel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=p45OwxQB05YC&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=tirata%20music&source=bl&ots=vH8b9bT8ZM&sig=ACfU3U0Wr9e532Zond7nS3KGlqJMUM8lsQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibkdjb9YbkAhWEc98KHUTdB3cQ6AEwDHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=tirata%20music&f=false) has

> *Tirata*: a rapid scalar passage, spanning a fourth to an octave or more.

This book contains some historical categorizations and characterization of what kind of ornaments are there. However, it seems like the "ascendence or descendence sequence of rapid notes" is a pretty universal definition.

The [Deutch Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirata) and [Russian musical encyclopedia](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_music/7545/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) might also be interesting sources. However, it is certainly a bit awkward to use this baroque ornament for Chopin's pieces, while it allows (in my mind) to distinguish between an arbitrary [*fioritura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fioritura) (as well pointed out by @Camille Goudeseune's answer) and an ornament that is strictly ascending in nature.

Comment: We just called them "runs" back in music school.